# Tango for mechanical engineering?

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to use tango for mechanical design. I would like to put scanned files on Autocad. Scanning existing pipes and steel structures. Is it possible with tango? For example with Zenfone AR?
Where can I find scanned stock samples to try with Autocad?

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of Tango applications on the Play Store that reconstruct 3D worlds on a scan. Google has written Constructor Developer Tool. The share feature inside Constructor creates a .zip file with a model and texture in .obj and .png formats.

I hope this helps!